# I followed Step 1 - Get Like Button Code and Step 2 - Get Open Graph Tags, no fb 'page' created

Tags: facebook-like

I've successfully integrated the open graph once on my site Neptuni.com and a 'page' was automatically created by the name of "Domaining@Neptuni". (It was an "Activity").

After some thoughts, I decided to change the opengraph tag to a "company" instead of an activity so I tried reintegrating by changing the open graph codes here and there, but the page remain unchanged by the codes thus I permanently deleted that page and started redoing the whole process.

Right now, I'm following the standard procedures again, but the company page doesn't seems to be automatically created this time round.. Help, anyone? :)